# Disable collapse on clicking twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is the collapse and working in its default nature. It closes when the user clicks "No". And It opens as well as closes when the user clicks "Yes".

I want to make it in such a way that it closes only when the user clicks "No" and open again only when the User clicks "Yes". If the user clicks "Yes" again, it should remained open.

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/18uyr3g9/)

```js
jQuery('.btn-active').click(function(e) {
  jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex btn-active " data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expolicy">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> No
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="collapse show" id="expolicy">
        This is the collapse. It opens/closes when the user clicks "Yes". It should close only when the user clicks "No" and open only when the User clicks "Yes". It is open by default.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The click event is being called when you click in the `label`, so I added an `id` to each label as you can see below.

Also, I removed the `data-toggle` from the `Yes` button, since it was always toggling the collapse without the need of your function, that way, only the function controls the toggle.

In the function, you check which button was pressed, if yes or no, then do what it should do.

```js
jQuery('.btn-active').click(function(e) {  
  if (e.target.id == "showCollapse"){ 
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('show');
  } else if (e.target.id == "hideCollapse"){
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex btn-active " data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active" data-target="#expolicy" id="showCollapse">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100" id="hideCollapse">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> No
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="collapse show" id="expolicy">
        This is the collapse. It opens/closes when the user clicks "Yes". It should close only when the user clicks "No" and open only when the User clicks "Yes". It is open by default.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also, by using two separate classes like **.btn-active1** and **.btn-active2**

also remove data-target="toggle"

```js
jQuery('.btn-active1').click(function(e) {
  jQuery('.collapse').collapse('show');
});
jQuery('.btn-active2').click(function(e) {
  jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active  btn-active1" data-toggle="" data-target="#expolicy">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100  btn-active2">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> No
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="collapse show" id="expolicy">
        This is the collapse. It opens/closes when the user clicks "Yes". It should close only when the user clicks "No" and open only when the User clicks "Yes". It is open by default.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `data-toggle` and `data-target` from label Yes as this will remove control from bootstrap.
put value="Yes" and value="No" for respective radio button and bind click handler for lables. on the basis of radio button value you can show or hide collapsible div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('label.w-100').click(function(e) {
   var value = $(this).find('input[type=radio][name=options]').val();
   if(value=='Yes') {
     jQuery('#expolicy').collapse('show');
   } else {
     jQuery('#expolicy').collapse('hide');
   }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/18uyr3g9/62/)